# FB.ui send doesn't send a message to user

Tags: facebook, api, fb.ui

I have a website with connected Facebook API. User is authorized via Facebook with the following permissions: offline_access, user_birthday, read_stream, publish_stream, email, user_about_me, user_website, user_location

I have a list of his friends (user's granted an access to it) and a "Send message" button for each of them. I call fb.ui method with the following options when user clicks on the button:

```
app_id:      fb_app_id,
to:          fb_user_id,
method:      'send', 
name:        'Message Title',
description: 'Message Text',
picture:     '/images/fb-icon-180x180.png',
link:        'http://facebook.com/'
```

The dialog itself is shown properly (the person I want to send it to is correct), but when I click save, a blank page is shown and no message is sent.

Is it a permission problem or there's a bug in my code? I tried it with and without app_id, but nothing helps.

Comment: Do you have Sandbox mode enabled?  You can't send messages to uses while sandbox is enabled.  Unless the user is registered as a developer on your Facebook account.

Comment: No, it's disabled and the app is active (we've been using in for more then a year)

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. It appeared that Facebook need a 200 response status code on the link you use in the fb.ui options. I have a 301 redirect there — that's why it didn't work.

Comment: And another weird thing: Facebook won't send a message via fb.ui send if a link value has characters in uppercase.

Comment: Here's to hoping you won't mind I add to this question/answer.
I'm trying to do more or less the same thing as you , but havent had any luck and can't find any related issues for my specific case anywhere :/
My case: I have created a fb login on my website (through a fb "app" to get a key etc). User1 and user2 both login on the site , allowing 'read_stream, publish_stream, email, user_about_me' to the app.
User1 and User2 are not friends. Now , can User1 send User2 a private message by using the fb.ui 'send' method ? (it seems to work in some occasions)  http://goo.gl/MGGsy